# What might a UK seed packet labeled "crfincr" contain?

Tags: identification, seeds

I have a packet of seeds labeled only: "crfincr". Any idea what they might be?

A clue in how this name is constructed is given in another packet labeled "baswlk" which means "basil (wilkinson's)".

I've planted them and they're coming up very slowly, with small frilly leaves.

Comment: the package must have been printed using a DOS program (8 letter limit)

Comment: Yeah I guessed as much, but the question is "what", not "why".

Comment: I  note you're in the UK - if wlk in the code for Basil stands for Wilkinsons, it might help if you could remember where you got these seeds from, because presumably, the last 2 3 or 4 letters refer to the supplier and not the seeds. Are they likely to be veg or flowers? If veg, something cruciferous?

Comment: They're from a box of assorted leftovers I found on the shelf. You now have all the information I have :-)

Comment: what do the seeds look like? size, color, texture? a photo of the seeds might be helpful

Comment: A photo of the seedlings too.  "very slowly" is vague; how long between planting and germination, and what conditions were they in for that time?

Comment: try to see if that is useful = CRF are part of antibodies (Corticotropin Releasing Factor), marginally related to plants: http://www.antibodies-online.com/antibody/234860/anti-Corticotropin+Releasing+Hormone+CRH/

Comment: photo of the plantlets might help, otherwise, its a wait and see...

Comment: My camera lens isn't good at close-ups, sorry.

Comment: creeping red fescue maybe?

Comment: Could you call the manufacturer?